# How to make fancybox tooltip (title) sticky without having to hover?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I am using fancybox and would like to display the title sticky without having the need to hover. Is there a way to do it ? My usage is strightforward, but couldn't find a way.

```
 <a class="imglarge-fancybox" rel="group" title="some title here"      
   href="http://imgur.com/some.jpg">
   <img class="imgsmall" alt src="http://imgur.com/small.jpg">
 </a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: please post your code so that we can try it..

Answer (score 0):

By a quick review on the FancyBox API i found this option `titleShow`

```
    titleShow ==> "Toggle title"
```